# Parseint in vuejs method

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

for example lets take `this.last` to be 5 and `this.current` 60 , I want `this.last` + `this.current` to be 65 and not 60 5. I tried `parseInt(this.last + this.current)` but it's not working

```html
<button class="plus" @click="plus">+</button>
<input class="res" v-model="current" maxlength="24" disabled>
<input class="res2" v-model="last" maxlength="24" disabled>
```

```css
button{
width:200px;
height:200px;
}
```

```js
data:{
  last: null,
  current: " ",
  plusClicked: false
}
methods:{
  plus:function(){
   this.last = this.current;
   this.current = " ";
   this.plusClicked = true;
  },
equal:function(){
  if(this.plusClicked == true){
   alert(parseInt(this.last + this.current));
   this.plusClicked = !true;
  }
}},
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, don't initialize `this.current` to `" "` but to `0`.

You should also change the type of the input field to `<input type="number">`.

To add both numbers use:

- `parseInt(this.last) + parseInt(this.current)`